# Elasticsearch Term aggregation taking too much time

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

Elasticsearch is taking too much time. I have the following kind of mappings.

**Mappings**

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
           "manufacture_id": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "product_id": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "seller_id": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "sell_amount": {
                "type": "double"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample documents**

```
[
        {
            "manufacture_id": 12,
            "product_id": 1,
            "seller_id": 1,
            "sell": 70
        },
        {
            "manufacture_id": 12,
            "product_id": 1,
            "seller_id": 1,
            "sell": 40
        },
        {
            "manufacture_id": 12,
            "product_id": 1,
            "seller_id": 2,
            "sell": 10
        },
        {
            "manufacture_id": 1234,
            "product_id": 2,
            "seller_id": 1,
            "sell": 20
        },
        {
            "manufacture_id": 1234,
            "product_id": 2,
            "seller_id": 2,
            "sell": 120
        },
        {
            "manufacture_id": 1234,
            "product_id": 2,
            "seller_id": 3,
            "sell": 90
        },
        {
            "manufacture_id": 1234,
            "product_id": 2,
            "seller_id": 3,
            "sell": 20
        }
    ]
```

What I want is the average sell of each product for a given manufacturer.

Query:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "manufacture_id": {
                            "query": 1234
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "products": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "product_id"
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "totalSell": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "sell"
                    }
                },
                "sellerCount": {
                    "cardinality": {
                        "field": "seller_id"
                    }
                },
                "avgSellOfProduct": {
                    "bucket_script": {
                        "buckets_path": {
                            "totalSellAmnt": "totalSell",
                            "totalSeller": "sellerCount"
                        },
                        "script": {
                            "source": "params.totalSellAmnt / params.totalSeller",
                            "lang": "painless"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have around 15 million documents for this manufacture id `1234`.
This query is taking time around 5 seconds to complete.

Is there any way to improve this search speed?

Also in this index, we have around 200 million documents (1 shard).

Any suggestion on how i manage this large amount of data?

Should i make multiple indexes?

Comment: nested aggregations are time consuming and impact the query performance. Should you make multiple indexes? Yes, you can go ahead and create multiple indexes. There's no downside in that. let me check and get back on if it's possible to improve speed in existing format.

Comment: @dravit can I make an index per manufacture? I have found out on the internet that too many indexes are creating issues. how should I divide this large amount of data across multiple indexes?

Comment: How many nodes (which specs) do you have and what's the volume in GB for those 15M docs?

Comment: @Rohit do you have access to the query/agg profiler? https://prnt.sc/yz102v

Comment: @JoeSorocin i don't have access to the query/agg profiler. can you tell me which tool is this I am not aware of this.

Comment: @Val it is around 32 GB of data for 200M docs.

Comment: @Val I have one node in which one primary shard.

Comment: Ok if you have a single index with only one primary shard on a single node (how much heap?) for querying 200M docs, then 5s probably make sense... If you add another node and add a replica shard to assign to that new node, then your performance is going to improve

Comment: @Val if i add more shards like 10 shard in this index this will improve performance?

Comment: If you add replicas shards, you need to add new nodes, otherwise those new shards will not be assignable as a node cannot hold more than one copy of the same data

Comment: I have noticed that the cardinality aggregation can also be very expensive when used on a lot of buckets. I believe it is trying to build an HLL sketch for each bucket which adds up pretty quickly.

Comment: @Val replica shard is already in a different node.

Comment: @rohit you mentioned earlier that you had a single node

Comment: @Val i mean to say that only 1 primary shard in one node.

Comment: @Val any suggestion on how should I manage this large amount of data on multiple shard or multiple indices so that I can get faster query results?